# How to increase the call volume in xolo q700

Tags: calls, volume-control

I have [xolo q700](http://www.xolo.in/q700), not sure if the problem is unique to my piece.  During the incoming/outgoing call, voice is not audible (very feeble), however speaker option and headphone provide good volume.

Is there any settings I can change to improve volume during my call in non-speaker/headphone mode?

Answer (score 1):

Try any Audio Manager app from play store.

[AudioManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartandroidapps.audiowidget)

[Audio Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aeh.ideos.amgr)

Answer (score 0):

**Instructions :**

1. List item
2. Enter **Engineering Mode** – Dial `*#*#3646633#*#*`
3. Go to **Hardware Testing → Audio → Normal Mode**.
4. Select “Sph” in type.
5. Select “level 6″ in Level.
6. Enter 160 in value.
7. Press **Set**.
8. Restart the phone.

It will increase your device's volume when you put your volume
to the highest level.

If you want to increase your volume in all levels then
choose from “level 0″ to “level 6″ and enter value you wish to. Max is 160, and min is 80.

Comment: Are you certain it's called "Engineering Mode" and not "EngineerMode"?